Как решить проблему с зависимостями в моем проекте?
Я запускаю проект на Create React App, и вижу ошибку, связанную с конфликтом версий пакета babel-jest. Я уже попробовал удалить package-lock.json, node_modules и пакет babel-jest из package.json, но проблема остается. Как я могу решить эту проблему?
[0] Starting child process with 'node index.js'
[0] Watching directory '/home/codervadim/message-project/server' for changes.
[0] Press rs for restarting the process.
[1]
[1] There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
[1] It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
[1]
[1] The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
[1]
[1]   "babel-jest": "^26.6.0"
[1]
[1] Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
[1] However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:
[1]
[1]   /home/codervadim/message-project/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 24.9.0)
[1]
[1] Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
[1]
[1] If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[1] That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
[1]
[1] To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
[1]
[1]   1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
[1]   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
[1]   3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
[1]   4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
[1]
[1] In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
[1] If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
[1]
[1]   5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
[1]      This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
[1]
[1]   6. Check if /home/codervadim/message-project/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
[1]      For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
[1]
[1]   7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
[1]      This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.
[1]
[1] If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[1] That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
[1]
[1] P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
[1]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[0] Server ready. Port: 5000
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[1] yarn client exited with code 1

